# strtok() behavior that I don't understand

Tags: c, string, split

[image]

I'm hoping to use `strtok()` in a C program I'm writing. I was trying to fiddle with it a little to jog my memory with it, and get back in practice with it, and ran into some behavior that I can't understand.

It seems like... my program is just exiting when I get to the strtok() call? I don't even get a seg fault, core dump, anything like that... the program just apparently stops running. I've no idea what's going on, or whether I'm doing something wrong.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

C file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello\n\n");
    
    char * str1 = "14:26";
    
    char * tokens1 = ":";
    char * curtok = strtok(str1, tokens1);
    printf("just got past first strtok() call.\n\n");
    
    printf("str1 is %s\n", str1);
    printf("tokens1 is %s\n", tokens1);
    printf("Is (curtok == (str1 + 2)) ? \n");
    if (curtok == (str1 + 2))
        printf("yes\n");
    else
        printf("no\n");
    printf("\n");
    
    curtok = strtok(NULL, "\0");
    printf("tokenizing for the null terminator.\n");
    printf("Is (curtok == (str1 + 5))? (Ie., did it give us the index of the null terminator?)\n");
    if (curtok == (str1 + 5))
        printf("yes\n");
    else
        printf("no\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output.

```
C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\WSU\Classes\20 - 21\WSU Spring 2021\cs360_sys_programming\pa4
> .\fiddling-with-strtok.exe
hello


C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\WSU\Classes\20 - 21\WSU Spring 2021\cs360_sys_programming\pa4
>
```

Using mingw on Windows, output of `gcc --version` is `gcc (tdm64-1) 5.1.0`. I got the same result when using an online C shell, see http://cpp.sh/52gwv .

I've previously used `strtok()` in other things I've done (for school), but maybe I'll just make my own string tokenizer for this program.

Comment: Update: ran it in a Linux installation (inside of WSL, the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which I've been using quite a bit for the stuff I've been doing recently)...
got a seg fault.

Comment: The string to tokenize can not be a literal, switch to `char str1[] = "14:26";`

Comment: `strtok` works by replacing the token with NULL characters, so the input should be writable.

Comment: excellent. thanks amigos.